# Set a different display resolution, but keep a 1:1 pixel ratio?

Tags: macos, display, resolution, aspect-ratio

I'm making a video where I have to record my display. The resolution of the video must be 1280x720, but my display has a nonstandard resolution (1440x900). When I set it to 1280x720, it fits to the whole display and blurs, sort of like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klutj.png).

Is there a way to resize the display like this, so the pixel ratio is still 1:1 and there's a black border around the whole screen? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1db6i.png)

I have a MacBook Air running the latest version of Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put up with the distortion for now, just put up with it, it won't affect the final result.

Once you've recorded the video, switch back to your regular resolution & the video will once more be 'normal'.

Comment: I know the video will look normal, but I'm asking if it's possible to change the resolution without distortion.

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, see above.